# Android DatePickerDialog - fails with IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-widget, datepicker, android-sdk-2.3, android-datepicker

Something odd that's happening on my Android emulator (Code and emulator run on API Level 10 - being Android 2.3.3): The current date on my emu is 22.08.2011 - if I initialize the DatePickerDialog with those settings (using the values from new Date() - which initializes the Date with the current date/time) then it fails, with the following exception:

```
08-22 02:14:23.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 02:14:23.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3038): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end
08-22 02:14:23.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.widget.NumberPicker.setCurrent(NumberPicker.java:288)
08-22 02:14:23.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.widget.DatePicker.updateSpinners(DatePicker.java:357)
08-22 02:14:23.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.widget.DatePicker.init(DatePicker.java:352)
08-22 02:14:23.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:127)
08-22 02:14:23.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:86)
```

So I checked out the [source Code for DatePicker](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/widget/DatePicker.java#DatePicker.updateSpinners%28%29) (For API lvl 2.3.3) and I checked the DatePicker code (because from the strack trace I knew it fails in the updateSpinners method) and at that line 357 (fourths line in the above stack trace) it calls mYearPicker.setCurrent(mYear); which made me think something must be wrong with my year. I logged the year I am passing - it's 2011 as expected. So I manually passed the year 2010 instead which worked - the DatePickerDialog showed up - initialized with the year 2010 (too bad, that I really need the current year - 2011 ;) ...).

I am a bit at a loss as to what the reason is for this... The date on my emulator - as mentioned above - is correctly set to 22.08.2011 - my dev PC is set to the same date...

Any clues/ideas as to where I am going wrong? To make things easier here is the code snippet where I am initializing the DatePickerDialog:

```
// Initializes a Date object with the current date and time for clarification:
// it is actually declared as a private member variable of my class - 
// just included it here so you guys know of which type dateTime ist

 Date dateTime = new Date();
 Button dateButton = new Button(context);
 dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// dateSetListener is declared as well - but its code has no influence on the failure of 
// the DatePickerDialog - to ensure this I commented all code in the dateSetListener's 
// onDateSet method 

                Dialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(v.getContext(), dateSetListener, dateTime.getYear(),
                        dateTime.getMonth(), dateTime.getDay());
                dateDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance & best regards,
Ready4Android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay after a bit more fiddeling I resorted to something I should have done WAY before: I logged the value of

```
//As in my example dateTime was initialized with new Date()
dateTime.getYear()
```

And the value the log showed was **111** ! I know this method is deprecated and apprently for good reasons... My mistake was to not verify that the value 2011 is returned - instead 111 is returned - as the documentation of getYear() says, it returns the years since 1900 - if we add 111 to 1900 we end up with 2011 ...  I was tempted for a second to simply add 1900 to the return value but sanity got the better of me and I decided to use the java class **Calendar** instead.

The reason why I was mislead at first is, that formatting my date using SimpleDateFormat resulted in the correct year - I did not consider the interior working of SimpleDateFormat, otherwise I might have had a clue that I am on the wrong track with my Date object.

To sum it up: There is no Problem with the DatePickerDialog - the problem was with the Date values I passed to it. However it would have been nice, if the error message would have mentioned the exact values instead of current should be >= ...

Comment: Good advice. I tend to use the **Calendar** class for getting and setting the date and the **Date** class for calculations and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will not compile, make `dateTime` field `final`. Also, have you declared `dateSetListener`?

Comment: Hello - it does compile and run ;) dateTime is not declared final but is a private member variable - in the code above I just included it in front of the OnClickListener so people know what kind of variable it is. And yes I also declared the dateSetListener - but it is not relevant for the problem, as it does nothing which prevents the dialog from working (to check this i commented the code in it - and it fails just as before).

Comment: P.s. If I had actually declared dateTime in the same method as where I am creating the button and the OnClickListener - then you'd be correct - it wouldnt compile and would have to be final. But as stated before - it is a private member variable - sorry for the confusion, I added a comment to clarify this.

Comment: Ok, i used the same code as above in my my example project, it gives me some error. Also  Dialog dateDialog, it is not working for me. But whe i change Dialog to DatePickerDialog, then it works fine for me.

Comment: Hello Sandy, mhhh I tried changing from Dialog to DatePickerDialog - to no avail :( same exception has before.